# How can I share a Facebook post on my timeline, but not the link object of that Facebook post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

Example post that I want to share: https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers/posts/10151471074398553

I expect sharing something like this:

[image]

So my friends could see the message "Be the first to know..." posted by Facebook Developers, and can read the comments of the post

However, when I'm sharing the link using URL, I can only get this:

[image]

My post is pointing to "Facebook Developer's Post's Link" now, but not the "Facebook Developer's Post"

Anyone have an idea on this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook has added the function "Include Original Post" now.

[image]

Comment: It seems that this no longer works...

Comment: @ThomasOrlita this only works if your target post is a Public post with link as attachment

Comment: The post is public but the attachment isn't a classic link but a "carousel" with images...

Comment: @ThomasOrlita I guess you may be referring to a "Post" with multiple images as the post's attachment? You can share that Post, and your share will contains that Post's description + attachments. But if you want to share what your friends typed when they shared that Post, that won't work, and is different from my original question. My original question is concerning on the first level of share, since sharing a post with link as the attachment will make me cannot share the post's description.

Answer (score 1):

To share another user's post that contains external links:

1. Paste the post link into your "Update Status" field (like you've done in the second screenshot).
2. Wait for Facebook to populate it with the rectangular preview image/box.
3. Hover your mouse over the image/box, and remove it by clicking the "X" in the upper right corner.

Doing this will allow you to share a direct link to someone else's Facebook post (ie, not the link that they've shared within their post). The only downside is that your post won't contain a "preview" of what you're sharing; just a link.

[NOTE: This method is only necessary when sharing a user's post that contains a *link*. If you're sharing a user's post that contains an *image*, any text that the user included with that image will also be shared.]

Comment: sorry that's clearly not what I wanted, being able to read the original message + the comment sections are important

Comment: If you follow my instructions, the original message and comments section *will* be there if someone clicks your link. You just won't see it in the preview.

Comment: When you share a link, would you delete the link preview but keep the hyperlink as a text copy for sharing? Don't want to start the debate here, but how Facebook handle object sharing is different from Twitter's hyperlink approach, so I'm sorry that I would not accept this as an answer, but this is really helpful so I'll still upvote it.

Comment: Correct: delete all the previews (sometimes there's one for an image and one for a headline), and then just share the URL as text. It'll appear as a hyperlink in your post, and when clicked, it'll take the user to the actual source post - which would include any comments from the source poster. It'll look just like the first screenshot above.

I share your frustrations, and wish there was an easier, more streamlined method. Hopefully Facebook will improve on it.